# Activity log not getting continuously updated in JavaFX

Tags: concurrency, javafx-2

I am executing some commands on linux using JSCH and taking output of that command and printing same on the activity log in my JAVAFX application.

Here is a problem: the activity log area is getting stuck after printing some line. But, if I switch from the window and back application continues to print lines on log area. I have debugged several times but wasn't able to catch the problem.

Below is the code

```
channel.connect();

PrintStream commander = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream(), true);
commander.println(command_cd);
commander.println(" exit;");
commander.close();


InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channel.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
String jarOutput;
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultLogFile.getAbsolutePath(), true));
while ((jarOutput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    this.logger.info("Status Update = " + jarOutput);
    System.out.print("Status Update on screen ="+jarOutput + "\n");
    bw.write(jarOutput);
    bw.newLine();
    outputFromUnix.append(jarOutput).append("\n");

    // Display in activity log area in realtime.
    if (DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea != null) {
        System.out.println("outputFromUnix.toString()---->>>>> " + outputFromUnix.toString());

    //actlogArea is TextArea

        DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.setText(outputFromUnix.toString());
        DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.end();

    }
}
bw.close();

reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX has a special thread named "JavaFX Application Thread" to update all UI. This thread shouldn't be used for any non-UI operations, and all UI operations **must** be run on that thread.

Make sure you run your code in a separate Thread and wrap all UI code into `Platform#runLater()` to have executed

```
// Using separate thread to run data loading code
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        channel.connect();

        // [...] all your channel reading code

        // Updating UI from JavaFX Application Thread
        if (DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea != null) {
            System.out.println("outputFromUnix.toString()---->>>>> " + outputFromUnix.toString());

            final String outputStr = outputFromUnix.toString();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.setText(outputStr);
                    DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.end();
                }
            });
        }
        bw.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}).start();
```

There is also a special concurrency API in JavaFX for such tasks, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm